# Remove 1px Border around List Web Part

Tags: web-part, list-view

I've created a tabbed section on a SharePoint 2016 page, containing a number of list web parts.  (I've used Christophe Humbert's Easy-Tabs-v5 to accomplish this, with modifications to suit the site's style theme.)

However, there is an unsightly 1px gap between the tab and its content:

[image]

This seems to be an allowance for the 1px blue border that appears when a list web part is selected.  I have come across several sets of instructions on how to remove that blue border, which has resolved my issue *for when the web part is **selected***.

[image]

I'd like the tabs to appear like the above, even when they are not selected.  Is there a way to remove this 1px white border allowance around ***unselected*** list view web parts?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I do not have access to SharePoint Designer, so would appreciate any suggestions that do not require this access.

Answer (score 1):

Quite impossible to answer this without full page HTML and CSS, but you can find the cause for that 1px border using browser DOM developer tools and override it with your own style. Sometimes it will take some thorough investigation what CSS class to override.

As this appears to be just one page, you can add this overriding piece of CSS into, e.g., Script Editor web part on the page where you have the tabbed UI.

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea as to what I should be looking for in the code?

Comment: I would assume it is caused by the "border", so try setting "border: 0" on the tab HTML elements to see which one is causing it.

Comment: Where can I find the tab HTML elements to change?  Each tab is a List web part so I can't see how to access the HTML the way you would for a CEWP.  (Note that CEWP does not have this issue - it seems to be isolated to List/Document View web parts.)

Comment: You don't want to change the actual HTML elements, but you want to add overriding CSS style (possibly by using !important on the style) on the page that will set border width to 0 (or whatever is needed).

Comment: I've scoured the code but everything already has border = none or border = 0px.  Is there anything else that it might be under? As I said, I've set the code to have an 0px border when the web part is selected, so is there a corresponding code that will allow me to do this when the web part is unselected?

Existing Code:

.s4-wpcell:hover .ms-WPHeader td, 
.s4-wpActive .ms-WPHeader td, 
.s4-wpcell .ms-WPSelected .ms-WPHeader td,
.s4-wpActive .s4-wpTopTable,
.s4-wpActive .ms-WPSelected {
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent !important;
    border: 0px solid transparent !important;